# using reactive expressions unreactivly in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I need to use:

```
session$clientData$url_search
```

which is a reactive expression but I don't want to use it in a reactive wrapper, i.e.

```
sessionData <- reactive({
  sessionData <- session$clientData$url_search
})
```

is there a way to now use this session data in a non reactive way? i.e.

```
url <- paste("http://example.web.ninja/,sessionData,sep="")
URLdata <- fromJSON(file=url,method='C')
```

without having to use:

```
URLdata <- reactive({
    url <- paste("http://example.web.ninja/,sessionData(),sep="")
    URLdata <- fromJSON(file=url,method='C')
 })
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm editing an older app that I made a while ago so that it now downloads its data from the web instead of the CSV file that I continued to update.  I want to do it because if I wrap URL data up in a reactive wrapper I continue to get errors like : Error in URLdata$Name : object of type closure is not subsettable

Comment: Have also tried the solution to this problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327506/r-shiny-how-to-save-input-data-to-the-server-or-access-input-variables-globally?rq=1

by trying to set the variables globally by using <<- but that did not work either

Comment: `Error in URLdata$Name ...` would indicate that the way to access the variable would be `URLdata()$Name`

Comment: That works ok until I then create a database using that reactive expression:
I create a loop to unpack the JSON file:

for(j in 1:numObs[1,tx]){
df[index,1] <- URLdata$Transformers[[i]]$Name
df[index,2] <- URLdata$Transformers[[i]]$dga[[j]]$Sampledate
... ect
how would it work in that context where I have a 16x11 dataframe

Comment: You can use `isolate` if you want to stop a chain of reactivity. So access the object with `isolate(URLdata()$Name)` and it wont be treated as a reactive variable within the reactive environment its called in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case the error:

```
Error in URLdata$Name : object of type closure is not subsettable
```

indicates that the object needs to be referenced as

```
URLdata()$Name
```

This results in a call to the reactive function. Calling a reactive variable within a reactive environment endows that reactive environment with a dependency on that reactive variable. Quickly things can cascade so there is a handy function `isolate` which allows one to call a reactive variable in a reactive environment and not bestow that dependency. In your case accessing the required object using

```
isolate(URLdata()$Name)
```

may be what you want.