# R / R Shiny - global dataframes array (assigned by reference)?

Tags: r, pass-by-reference, shiny

I have a dataframe df1, and subset it to df1sub and display it in an R shiny renderPlot() call. Similarly, I have df2, and I subset it to df2sub, and render it in R shiny via a separate renderPlot() call. Btw these subsets are created based on user choices in an R Shiny app.

Now, I have a datatable that I want to change to reflect whatever the current dataset is, so I wanted some kind of global like:

```
buffers[1] <- df1sub
buffers[2] <- df2sub
```

How would I go about defining this global var? I tried separately doing buffers = array() to initialize a global var but then the assignments as I wrote them above don't work?

**Update**: attempts to use the the '**<<-**' operator as suggested below yields the following:

```
buffers <- NULL #don't know how else to initialize. array() yields same error as below.
buffers[1] <<- df # Error in buffers[1] <<- df : object 'buffers' not found
```

Comment: If the data changes should be available in other reactive functions as well you might want to look at `reactiveValues` [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactiveValues.html)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327506/r-shiny-how-to-save-input-data-to-the-server-or-access-input-variables-globally ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adopt this approach:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  ...
  some.reactive.expression <- reactive1({
     ...
     buffers[1] <<- df1sub
     buffers[2] <<- df2sub
     ...
  })
})
```

With some updates:

```
#In global.R
buffers <- list()
buffers[[1]] <- data.frame()
buffers[[2]] <- data.frame()
buffers[[1]] <- df1 #original dataset, as a default, before subsets are created
buffers[[2]] <- df2 #ditto.
```

Then in server.R:

```
r1 <- reactive({
... #create subset of df, then return it
buffers[[1]] <<- subset(...)
buffers[[1]] #return it as dynamic data for plots
})

r2 <- reactive({...}) #ditto
```

then in renderplot:

```
output$blah <- renderplot(r1()...)
output$foo <- renderplot(r2()...)
```

Leaving the global buffers[] var separately available to a 3rd UI widget (e.g. a data table)...

Comment: wow... I have literally never come across that operator till now, and had to google it :-) I'm going to try this out and will come back soon to accept answer...

Comment: Quick Q: does doing 'df <- buffers[1]' inside renderPlot() defeat the object? i.e. will it try to do copy by value at that point? nm... just tried it. I get an error saying 'ERROR:argument is of length zero'

Comment: I guess it could happen because `buffers` is a vector. Could you try `buffers <- list()` and `buffers[[1]] <<- df1sub; buffers[[2]] <<- df2sub` instead?

Comment: no joy there either... with list() it does not work, but it looks promising: at least now I start with a list of length 0. I am learning a lot from all your examples, lol.
UPDATE: list() I tried assigning buffers[[1]] <- data.frame() first. This works with the regular assignments, but not with the '<<-' operator.

Comment: That's weird... I'm not sure if I have any ideas until I see the actual code.

Comment: This is what worked: used '<-' in a global.R to define and set initial values using list(), data.frame(). in server.R, I then used the '<<-' to assign dynamic subsets to the global df list. this was inside a reactive() function like you have shown above. The last step is to make the reactive function return the subset: 'buffers[[x]]'. I could then just use the reactive expression directly to generate dynamic plots. You have helped a lot... I can accept your answer even though it is not exact?

Comment: Glad to help. About up-voting -- it's really up to you, I don't take these things very seriously )